# The Movie Database: Return Movie Overview JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

Learning how to connect an API up using The Movie Database with JSON. Right now I'm able to call the database and return "poster_path", "original_title", and "release_date". I found a ton of questions on how to hook the call up but nothing specifically that tells me how to get a movie overview. I'm also a bit fuzzy following their provided documentation.

What I would like to do is return the "overview" of each movie. Currently I do not see an overview param in the array objects when I do a console.log(json).

Example of what I would like to return can be found on any movie page [Expendables 3](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/138103-the-expendables-3), under ***overview*** section on a movie page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
            mode = 'search/movie?query=',
            input,
            movieName,
            key = '&api_key=<api_key>';

    $('#search').on('click', function() {
        var input = $('#term').val(),
                movieName = encodeURI(input);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + mode + input + key,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'testing',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                jQuery.each(json.results, function (key, val) {
                    /*playing around with different keywords "overview", "primary_info" and others I randomly inserted and all returned undefined*/
                    /*console.log(json.results[key].poster_path);
                    console.log(json.results[key].original_title);
                    console.log(json.results[key].release_date);*/
                    console.log(json);
                });
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }).done(function(){
            $('.movieSearch').find("input[type=text]").val("");
        });
    });

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if more information is needed in solving this problem will gladly provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I was able to run a second AJAX call in the success function of the first AJAX call. Then I grabbed the ID of the object I needed the "overview" for, passed that through the url and obtained the correct overview param.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + mode + input + key,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'testing',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                jQuery.each(json.results, function (key, val) {
                    console.log(json.results[key].id);
                });
                console.log(json);
                var first = json.results[0].id;
                console.log(first);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: url + 'movie/' + first + '?' + key,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        jsonpCallback: 'testing',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(json) {
                            console.log(json.overview);
                        },
                        error: function(e) {}
                    }).done();
            },
            error: function(e) {}
        }).done();
```

Again thanks for the help guys and getting me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making a `/search/movie?query={phrase}` call. That call will return summary information for a list of movies that match the query. An `id` value is returned for each movie in the list. You can then use that `id` in a subsequent `/movie/{id}` call to get the details for the movie. The details will include the overview.

Comment: console.log(json.results[key].id) With that I'm able to return the id number of the movie. What I'm finding difficult is using that to grab subsequent information with in the json object. Is there a chance you can provide a quick example? Do I need to to use the &append_to_response=####?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no json.requests. You can access property of json through dot notation.

```
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    console.log(json.poster_path);
    console.log(json.production_companies.name);
},
```

Comment: In the question I asked, I am using console.log(json.results[key].original_title); to bring back elements which is working. But I don't have a param for overview

Comment: Yes that's the API I'm using

Comment: You have to request another API "/movie/{id}" to get overview

Comment: I'm reading that I have to make a 2nd request to pull the ID to get the overview. So my question now is how do I make a second request to use the ID to grab another request?

Comment: You could call ajax in success function but it will make your code slow

Comment: Was able to use an ajax function in the success call. From what I read here [link](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/511d6190760ee324ba051564) it's the only way to get this to work. Thankfully only pulling it for one movie which shouldn't be too bad.